# IntelliJ gives error access denied when I try to do perform "reload changed classes" from run menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am using IntelliJ version 14.1.4 on Windows 7 64bit with oracle JDK 1.8.45.

When I change a method logic etc and click on "reload changed classes" from run menu, I get following error-

[image]

I've tried running IntelliJ as admin also, invalidating cache but that doesn't seem to help.

Note that I am using Jetty maven plugin to run my web application.

Comment: I'm guessing you ran this as admin at some point in the past and your user is unable to write over them, but it could also be another process that's running and accessing the file as well.  Quit your IDE, insure no java process is running, delete your class files manually and then fire it back up again.

Comment: @HeathMalmstrom unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: Did you kill your jetty maven execution?  This could be file level locking it (or another application if it were using that file for something on windows.

Comment: I actually verified using Process Explorer that only process who has handle on it is java debugger - which makes sense. Jetty-maven plugin is running under the debugger not as a separate process

Comment: Still sounds to me like you have contention between jetty-maven plugin and your IDE trying to compile.  Make sure you are not using the same directory for IDE compilation class files as you are for your outputDirrectory in your pom configuration (or classesDirectory).

Comment: @HeathMalmstrom thanks for the input, I was actually able to work around it, going to post answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @HeathMalmstrom, Jetty maven plugin doesn't play nice when trying to reload changed classes. What I did was instead of using Jetty maven plugin, I wrote a class with a main method which embeds Jetty; now I run this class under debugger and everything works fine.